# Admob ad banner size on android

Tags: android, admob, banner

Use

```
adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
```

in the layout is it paied more than using "BANNER" ?

On admob, on android.

Comment: Can you provide an update? or at least accept my answere if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and no!**

No, because at [Google Admob Support Page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3544756?hl=en) they don't mention anything about more revenue with bigger banners! You get paid per clicks or per impressions depending for what the advertiser wants to pay.

Yes, because i think you are thinking about that the wrong way. Bigger banner sizes can lead to more clicks as smaller ones. Which can again lead into more revenue...